# Firebase prevent "Password" Registration spamming

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I have an application running on Firebase, and i noticed an usual registration in my database. So, i went through my code to find the issue. And realised if I write this code in my browser console.

```
 var xs = new Firebase('<My-firebase-url>')
 xs.createUser({
    email: 'email@mail.com',
    password: 'passwrd'
  }, function(error, userData) {
    console.log(userData, error) //creates a new user
   })
```

It creates a new user in my database. How can I restrict this from happening with Firebase or angular or node-js or any other way I can go about stopping this registration spam.

Thanks.

Comment: So no one answered this yet, hmm

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe that is something you would need to worry about since your firebase url is not something people would have access to unless the server is compromised or something.

Comment: The whole point of Firebase is that it is your server, and you can access it from the front end.

Comment: Security through obscurity, also, is quite easy to read the javascript code and search for new Firebase(yourUrl)